# Why this severe and so long time suspension?

Tags: discussion

I just have started answering one of today's questions before wanting to link a related existing answer on this website and falling on [this user's profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/10787/andrew-smith).

First of all, I never had an interaction with that user or knew his existence before a moment ago, so please do not consider my post from any negative stand point.

I read some of his answers and comment: they are interesting so I am *shocked* that he is suspended for 11 years (!!!)

Surely I am not competent to be a moderator and I do not pretend to be one day better than them in this job, however I wonder if it is not too severe to block him during more than a decade and prevent people from learning from him especially that 4 days ago he logged back (a sign he would love to be active). I think in an extreme case, a user can be banned for one year at maximum because no one is a terrorist here, all members register to learn and or share their experience and help.

Comment: *Some* users ARE terrorists, or at least try to be. (Terrorists as in terrorizing people, not necessarily blowing up busses.)

Comment: I would rather refrain from getting into the details, especially as most of the worst parts have already been removed (which would explain why you don't see them :-) ), so no reason to spill it out all over again. I will say that, while I was not the mod that gave him the final suspension, it *was* justified. It is arguable whether 11 years is too much, or if 7.5 years would have sufficed, but at that point I guess it doesn't really matter :-). Point is, the many shorter suspensions that he had (as we usually do), did not work, and only exacerbated the situation.

Comment: @AviD I agree with you that it may not be polite to divulgue what he did just by respect (even if he is anonymous) but I just find the time of suspension too severe. However, as I said before, I can not judge better than you. Regards

Comment: thanks for the vote of confidence :-). The point of "11 years" is really just "permanently, for now". Like I said, it could just as well have been 7 years, but the difference is academic. Some users are just persona non grata, despite the occasional decent answer.

Comment: A reading on subject I found very interesting: [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). I specially encourage you to read the pages Jeff Atwood links in his first comment dealing with the "*Bad apple*" theory.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Thank you very much for the link. I bookmarked it to read it in 2 hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the final suspension was from me (after many shorter suspensions) and if there had been an option for permanent ban that is what I would have selected.

That user demonstrated that they had no intention of following site rules in any way.

Within hours of logging back in after suspensions (seconds, sometimes) they would deliberately break rules, offend others etc.

This is not an individual we want here.